# Can't Display Message Dialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a class that contains some QPushButtons and whenever I press a button, I want the program to display a message saying that the action has been carried out. So far I have tried to create a QMessageBox and call it within the button function below it but it doesn't work. I keep getting a compiler error. Here is my code and my stack trace. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
# import Statements
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from reportViewerWindow import Ui_reportViewerWindow
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
import os


# Main Class that holds User Interface Objects
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    # Function for Opening Report Viewer Window From Main Window by clicking View Reports button
    def openReportViewer(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_reportViewerWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()


    # Main window setup
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(834, 428)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: Cornflowerblue")
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        # Sim Card Button
        self.simCardButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.simCardButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 211, 30))
        self.simCardButton.setToolTip("This option extracts all sim card data that is stored on the suspect devices sim card")
        self.simCardButton.setToolTip("This data relates to all stored sim data on the suspect device")
        self.simCardButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.simCardButton.setFont(font)
        self.simCardButton.setObjectName("simCardButton")


        # Call Logs Button
        self.callLogButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.callLogButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 300, 211, 30))
        self.callLogButton.setToolTip("This option extracts all call log data that is stored on the suspect device")
        self.callLogButton.setToolTip("This data relates to all incoming or outgoing phone calls stored on the suspect device")
        self.callLogButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.callLogButton.setFont(font)
        self.callLogButton.setObjectName("callLogButton")


        # SMS Button
        self.smsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.smsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 211, 30))
        self.smsButton.setToolTip("This option extracts all text message data that is stored on the device")
        self.smsButton.setToolTip("This data relates to all text messages that have been sent and received on the suspect device")
        self.smsButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smsButton.setFont(font)
        self.smsButton.setObjectName("smsButton")


        # Canonical Address Button
        self.canonicalAddressesButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 211, 30))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setToolTip("This option extracts all text message data that is stored on the device")
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setToolTip("This data relates to all devices that have been in contact with the suspect device")
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setFont(font)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setObjectName("canonicalAddressesButton")


        # Main Window Label
        self.windowMainLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.windowMainLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 20, 500, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.windowMainLabel.setFont(font)
        self.windowMainLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.windowMainLabel.setObjectName("windowMainLabel")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 291, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")


        # # View Reports Button
        self.viewReportsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.viewReportsButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.viewReportsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 370, 175, 31))
        self.viewReportsButton.clicked.connect(self.openReportViewer)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.viewReportsButton.setFont(font)
        self.viewReportsButton.setObjectName("viewReportsButton")
        self.viewReportsButton.setEnabled(False)


        # Label for evidence viewer
        self.evidenceViewingLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 120, 141, 16))
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setObjectName("evidenceViewingLabel")

        # Buttons for report generation
        self.generate_canonical_report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate_canonical_report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 150, 175, 31))
        self.generate_canonical_report.setObjectName("generate_canonical_report")
        self.generate_canonical_report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generate_canonical_report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generate_Sim_Report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 190, 175, 31))
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setObjectName("generate_sim_report")
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generateSMS_Report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generateSMS_Report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 230, 175, 31))
        self.generateSMS_Report.setObjectName("generate_sms_report")
        self.generateSMS_Report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generateSMS_Report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generate_callLog_report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate_callLog_report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 270, 175, 31))
        self.generate_callLog_report.setObjectName("generate_callLog_report")
        self.generate_callLog_report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generate_callLog_report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generateFullReportButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generateFullReportButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 310, 175, 31))
        self.generateFullReportButton.setObjectName("generateFullReportButton")
        self.generateFullReportButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generateFullReportButton.setEnabled(False)



        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionOpen_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_2.setObjectName("actionOpen_2")
        self.actionExit_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit_2.setObjectName("actionExit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    # Function that sets the text on all the UI Buttons
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Data Parser"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data Parsing Options"))
        self.simCardButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sim Card"))
        self.callLogButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Call Logs"))
        self.smsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS "))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Addresses"))
        self.windowMainLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "AMF Parser"))

        # Report Button set text and tool_tips
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Report Generator"))

        self.generate_canonical_report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Report"))
        self.generate_canonical_report.setToolTip("Select to generate canonical address report")

        self.generate_Sim_Report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sim Report"))
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setToolTip("Select to generate sim card report")

        self.generateSMS_Report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS Report"))
        self.generateSMS_Report.setToolTip("Select to generate sms report")

        self.generate_callLog_report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Call Log Report"))
        self.generate_callLog_report.setToolTip("Select to generate call log report")

        self.viewReportsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "View Reports"))
        self.viewReportsButton.setToolTip("Select to open report viewing window")

        self.generateFullReportButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Full Report"))
        self.generateFullReportButton.setToolTip("Select to generate full report")

        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionOpen_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

    # Event Handling Code Section



        # Parsing Area!!!

        # Canonical Addresses Button click functionality to parse canonical address data
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.select_canonical_data)

        # Sim Card Button click functionality to parse sim card data
        self.simCardButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sim_data)

        # Call Logs Button click functionality to parse call log data
        self.callLogButton.clicked.connect(self.select_call_data)

        # SMS Button click functionality to parse SMS data
        self.smsButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sms_data)

        # Reporting Area!!!
        # Report Generation Functions!!!
        self.one_pass = False
        self.two_pass = False
        self.three_pass = False
        self.four_pass = False
        self.five_pass = False

        # canonical address report generating functionality
        self.generate_canonical_report.clicked.connect(self.generate_canonicalR)

        # sim card report generating functionality
        self.generate_Sim_Report.clicked.connect(self.generate_simR)

        # sms report generating functionality
        self.generateSMS_Report.clicked.connect(self.generate_smsR)

        # call log report generating functionality
        self.generate_callLog_report.clicked.connect(self.generate_call_LogR)

        # All data report
        self.generateFullReportButton.clicked.connect(self.generate_full_reportR)

        # Data Parsed Dialog Box (This is where my problem is)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification)

    def data_parsed_notification(self):
        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msgBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Data Has Been Parsed!', QMessageBox.StandardButtons)

    # Canonical Addresses button function
    def select_canonical_data(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification)
        self.generate_canonical_report.setEnabled(True)

    # call log button function
    def select_call_data(self):
        os.system('CallLogParser.py')
        self.generate_callLog_report.setEnabled(True)

    # sms button function
    def select_sms_data(self):
        os.system('SmsParser.py')
        self.generateSMS_Report.setEnabled(True)

    # sim card button function
    def select_sim_data(self):
        os.system('SimCardParser.py')
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(True)

    # report generation functions
    def generate_canonicalR(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressReporter.py')
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()

    def generate_simR(self):
        os.system('SimCardReporter.py')
        self.generateSMS_Report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()

    def generate_smsR(self):
        os.system('SmsDataReporter.py')
        self.generate_callLog_report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()

    def generate_call_LogR(self):
        os.system('CallLogReporter.py')
        self.check_run_button()
        self.generateFullReportButton.setEnabled(True)

    def generate_full_reportR(self):
        os.system('AllDataReport.py')
        self.check_run_button()
        self.viewReportsButton.setEnabled(True)

    def check_run_button(self):
        if self.one_pass == self.two_pass == self.three_pass == self.four_pass is True:
            self.generateFullReportButton.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Stack Trace

```
line 270, in data_parsed_notification
    msgBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Data Has Been Parsed!', QMessageBox.StandardButtons)
TypeError: QMessageBox.information(QWidget, str, str, QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'
```

Changing to self.window

```
self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification)
    window = QtWidgets
    def data_parsed_notification(self):
        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msgBox.information(self.window, 'Message', 'Data Has Been Parsed!', QMessageBox.StandardButtons)
```

Comment: If you have another problem, create another question. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short solution:**

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    self.mainwindow = MainWindow
    [...]

def data_parsed_notification(self):
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self.mainwindow, 'Message', 'Data Has Been Parsed!', QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
```

The short solution can solve your current problem but I think that in the long run you will have more problems of the same type, so even though it is easy to implement I recommend using the long solution as it will avoid other problems.

**Long solution:**

The class that generates Qt Designer is not a widget, it is a class that serves to fill a widget, and because the `information()` method of `QMessageBox` requires a `QWidget` is generating that type of errors.

What is recommended is not to modify the design, that is, you should leave the design as it is and create another .py file that is responsible for managing the logic so you can modify your design again without having to rewrite anything back.

Assuming you have restored the design and that file we can call it ui_mainwindow.py:

**ui_mainwindow.py**

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

    # Main window setup
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        [...]

    # Function that sets the text on all the UI Buttons
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        [...]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then create another file called **main.py** where we will create the widget and use the design to fill it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from reportViewerWindow import Ui_reportViewerWindow
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class ReportViewerWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_reportViewerWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and in this new class your logic is implemented, the above is a brief summary but then I will place all the code:

Complete Code:

**ui_mainwindow.py**

```
# Main GUI Window for parser
# Daniel Mc Henry
# Project Development
# CSDF 2017/2018
# L00113325

# import Statements
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# Main Class that holds User Interface Objects
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    # Main window setup
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(834, 428)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: Cornflowerblue")
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        # Sim Card Button
        self.simCardButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.simCardButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 211, 30))
        self.simCardButton.setToolTip("This option extracts all sim card data that is stored on the suspect devices sim card")
        self.simCardButton.setToolTip("This data relates to all stored sim data on the suspect device")
        self.simCardButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.simCardButton.setFont(font)
        self.simCardButton.setObjectName("simCardButton")


        # Call Logs Button
        self.callLogButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.callLogButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 300, 211, 30))
        self.callLogButton.setToolTip("This option extracts all call log data that is stored on the suspect device")
        self.callLogButton.setToolTip("This data relates to all incoming or outgoing phone calls stored on the suspect device")
        self.callLogButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.callLogButton.setFont(font)
        self.callLogButton.setObjectName("callLogButton")


        # SMS Button
        self.smsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.smsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 211, 30))
        self.smsButton.setToolTip("This option extracts all text message data that is stored on the device")
        self.smsButton.setToolTip("This data relates to all text messages that have been sent and received on the suspect device")
        self.smsButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smsButton.setFont(font)
        self.smsButton.setObjectName("smsButton")


        # Canonical Address Button
        self.canonicalAddressesButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 211, 30))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setToolTip("This option extracts all text message data that is stored on the device")
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setToolTip("This data relates to all devices that have been in contact with the suspect device")
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setFont(font)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setObjectName("canonicalAddressesButton")


        # Main Window Label
        self.windowMainLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.windowMainLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 20, 500, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.windowMainLabel.setFont(font)
        self.windowMainLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.windowMainLabel.setObjectName("windowMainLabel")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 291, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")


        # # View Reports Button
        self.viewReportsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.viewReportsButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.viewReportsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 370, 175, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.viewReportsButton.setFont(font)
        self.viewReportsButton.setObjectName("viewReportsButton")
        self.viewReportsButton.setEnabled(False)


        # Label for evidence viewer
        self.evidenceViewingLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 120, 141, 16))
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setObjectName("evidenceViewingLabel")

        # Buttons for report generation
        self.generate_canonical_report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate_canonical_report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 150, 175, 31))
        self.generate_canonical_report.setObjectName("generate_canonical_report")
        self.generate_canonical_report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generate_canonical_report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generate_Sim_Report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 190, 175, 31))
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setObjectName("generate_sim_report")
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generateSMS_Report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generateSMS_Report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 230, 175, 31))
        self.generateSMS_Report.setObjectName("generate_sms_report")
        self.generateSMS_Report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generateSMS_Report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generate_callLog_report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate_callLog_report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 270, 175, 31))
        self.generate_callLog_report.setObjectName("generate_callLog_report")
        self.generate_callLog_report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generate_callLog_report.setEnabled(False)

        self.generateFullReportButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generateFullReportButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 310, 175, 31))
        self.generateFullReportButton.setObjectName("generateFullReportButton")
        self.generateFullReportButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generateFullReportButton.setEnabled(False)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionOpen_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_2.setObjectName("actionOpen_2")
        self.actionExit_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit_2.setObjectName("actionExit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    # Function that sets the text on all the UI Buttons
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Data Parser"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data Parsing Options"))
        self.simCardButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sim Card"))
        self.callLogButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Call Logs"))
        self.smsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS "))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Addresses"))
        self.windowMainLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "AMF Parser"))

        # Report Button set text and tool_tips
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Report Generator"))

        self.generate_canonical_report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Report"))
        self.generate_canonical_report.setToolTip("Select to generate canonical address report")

        self.generate_Sim_Report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sim Report"))
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setToolTip("Select to generate sim card report")

        self.generateSMS_Report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS Report"))
        self.generateSMS_Report.setToolTip("Select to generate sms report")

        self.generate_callLog_report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Call Log Report"))
        self.generate_callLog_report.setToolTip("Select to generate call log report")

        self.viewReportsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "View Reports"))
        self.viewReportsButton.setToolTip("Select to open report viewing window")

        self.generateFullReportButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Full Report"))
        self.generateFullReportButton.setToolTip("Select to generate full report")

        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionOpen_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import os

from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from reportViewerWindow import Ui_reportViewerWindow

class ReportViewerWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_reportViewerWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

    # Event Handling Code Section
        # Parsing Area!!!

        # Canonical Addresses Button click functionality to parse canonical address data
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.select_canonical_data)

        # Sim Card Button click functionality to parse sim card data
        self.simCardButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sim_data)

        # Call Logs Button click functionality to parse call log data
        self.callLogButton.clicked.connect(self.select_call_data)

        # SMS Button click functionality to parse SMS data
        self.smsButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sms_data)

        # Reporting Area!!!
        # Report Generation Functions!!!
        self.one_pass = False
        self.two_pass = False
        self.three_pass = False
        self.four_pass = False
        self.five_pass = False

        # canonical address report generating functionality
        self.generate_canonical_report.clicked.connect(self.generate_canonicalR)

        # sim card report generating functionality
        self.generate_Sim_Report.clicked.connect(self.generate_simR)

        # sms report generating functionality
        self.generateSMS_Report.clicked.connect(self.generate_smsR)

        # call log report generating functionality
        self.generate_callLog_report.clicked.connect(self.generate_call_LogR)

        # All data report
        self.generateFullReportButton.clicked.connect(self.generate_full_reportR)

        # Data Parsed Dialog Box (This is where my problem is)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification)

        self.viewReportsButton.clicked.connect(self.openReportViewer)

    def openReportViewer(self):
        self.window = ReportViewerWindow()
        self.window.show()

    def data_parsed_notification(self):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Data Has Been Parsed!', QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)

    # Canonical Addresses button function
    def select_canonical_data(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification)
        self.generate_canonical_report.setEnabled(True)

    # call log button function
    def select_call_data(self):
        os.system('CallLogParser.py')
        self.generate_callLog_report.setEnabled(True)

    # sms button function
    def select_sms_data(self):
        os.system('SmsParser.py')
        self.generateSMS_Report.setEnabled(True)

    # sim card button function
    def select_sim_data(self):
        os.system('SimCardParser.py')
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(True)

    # report generation functions
    def generate_canonicalR(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressReporter.py')
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()

    def generate_simR(self):
        os.system('SimCardReporter.py')
        self.generateSMS_Report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()

    def generate_smsR(self):
        os.system('SmsDataReporter.py')
        self.generate_callLog_report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()

    def generate_call_LogR(self):
        os.system('CallLogReporter.py')
        self.check_run_button()
        self.generateFullReportButton.setEnabled(True)

    def generate_full_reportR(self):
        os.system('AllDataReport.py')
        self.check_run_button()
        self.viewReportsButton.setEnabled(True)

    def check_run_button(self):
        if self.one_pass == self.two_pass == self.three_pass == self.four_pass is True:
            self.generateFullReportButton.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm assuming that all the files are in the same folder:

```
├── AllDataReport.py
├── CallLogParser.py
├── CallLogReporter.py
├── CanonicalAddressesParser.py
├── CanonicalAddressReporter.py
├── main.py
├── reportViewerWindow.py
├── SimCardReporter.py
├── SmsDataReporter.py
├── SmsParser.py
└── ui_mainwindow.py
```

**Plus:**

If you want to change the color of the button inside the `QMessageBox` you must use:

```
QtWidgets.qApp.setStyleSheet("QMessageBox QPushButton{background-color: Silver;}")
```

Comment: Yes all files are under the same directory in a project-type structure.

Comment: For the short solution, how do I change the OK button to silver as it is the same colour as the messagebox itself?

Comment: The dialog boxes were the last thing I had to do in the program so I have no need to migrate to the long solution but I will keep it in mind for future redevelopment purposes

Comment: @GreenCoder90 So I guess my short or long answer will help you, if so, please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Can You direct me first though as to how i can change the message box ok button background

Comment: @GreenCoder90 I added that in my answer, check it

Comment: Where does this: QtWidgets.qApp.setStyleSheet("QMessageBox QPushButton{background-color: Silver;}") go in my code?

Comment: @GreenCoder90 Anywhere you run before showing the QMessageBox, you should try to do things before asking, if it should be placed in a specific place I would have said in my answer.

Comment: Just asking buddy.

Comment: @ eyllanesc when I put this: QtWidgets.qApp.setStyleSheet("QMessageBox QPushButton{background-color: Silver;}")  inside a function where each QMessage box is fired, it does not do anything and when I do press the button, it makes the text in the buttons at the other side of my GUI smaller which is strange. What is the correct way of doing this. I have tried to put it inside a function as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of QMessageBox constructor must be a QWidget (or an instance of a subclass of QWidget), but you're passing a Ui_MainWindow object.
The parent for your message box should be MainWindow.

In the setupUi() function, add `self.mainwindow = MainWindow`.

Then you should replace this line 
`msgBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Data Has Been Parsed!', QMessageBox.StandardButtons)` 
by
`msgBox.information(self.mainwindow, 'Message', 'Data Has Been Parsed!', QMessageBox.StandardButtons)`

Comment: what is `self.window`?

Comment: You're right, I've misread his code.
The parent of the QMessageBox should be MainWindow, so in the setupUi() function, he should keep track of it with something like `self.mainwindow = MainWindow` and use this as the first parameter of QmessageBox.information().

Comment: your answer is valid?

Comment: I have put in an attempt of what you suggested. Check above. I think its still wrong

Comment: Still Getting AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'mainwindow' after replacing code with msgBox.information(self.mainwindow, 'Message', 'Data Has Been Parsed!', QMessageBox.StandardButtons). I don't understand why this is not working for me.

Comment: You didn't add `self.mainwindow = MainWindow` to the `setupUI` function